# Gerrit - additive Verified label (1+1=2)?

Tags: prolog, gerrit

For a project I'm working on we run test suites on both a windows and a linux build agent. I'd like to make it so that people can only merge patches if both test suites pass but by default Gerrit treats two +1's as still being +1. We already use a rules.pl file like the example here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#_example_13_1_1_2_code_review to do this for code reviews but I'm not familiar with prolog and I have not been able to figure out how to make the same logic also apply to the Verified label. Is there even a way to do this?

Comment: First: does your "Verified" label need a +2 to be approved? I'm asking that because the default is just a +1 for this label. Answer that: have you tried to replace "Code-Review" for "Verified" in https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#_example_13_1_1_2_code_review?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately even when setting verified to require +2 multiple +1's still just equal +1 so it's' never approved. I've tried modifying the code review example in the docs but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @RachelHutchison Did you actually found solution? I'm also having same problem. i would need to have three +1 on Verified label. Then it would allow submit.